# How to integrate grafana and locust?

Tags: grafana, locust

Is there any way to integrate locust and grafana? I have tried from this [link](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/locust-monitoring-with-grafana-in-just-fifteen-minutes/), there are no errors but also there is no data coming to graphite. can someone help on this?